# splitting list elements in python

Tags: python

There is a list of elements in python in the following form:

```
['96\t00:00:00:19\t-16,894725\t15,201475\t26,976\t52,471\t10,081275\t42,177475\t32,0962']
['97\t00:00:00:19\t-17,007775\t15,198775\t26,979\t52,471\t9,971225\t42,177775\t32,20655']
['98\t00:00:00:19\t-17,010475\t15,204175\t26,977\t52,471\t9,966525\t42,181175\t32,21465']
['99\t00:00:00:19\t-16,9997\t15,1907\t26,981\t52,473\t9,9813\t42,1717\t32,1904']
['100\t00:00:00:20\t-17,0024\t15,17995\t26,979\t52,476\t9,9766\t42,15895\t32,18235']
```

UPDATED:

I am using the following code:

```
import os
import csv

dirlisting=os.listdir(os.getcwd())

for fname in dirlisting:
if fname.endswith(".csv"):
    print "Processing: " + fname
    fi=open(fname, 'rb')
    data=fi.read()
    fi.close()
    fo=open(fname, 'wb')
    fo.write(data.replace('\x00', ''))
    fo.close()

    with open(fname, 'rb') as csvfile:
        sreader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')             
        rows=[r for r in sreader]
        for row in range(6, len(rows)):
            print rows[row]
```

I need to split this list elements or to convert them in some other form so that they can be further processed.

Comment: To what form do you want to convert them? Also, what you’ve written here is five separate lists… did you mean to write that the five strings are in the same list together?

Comment: Is this the actual format of your data?  What you have in the codeblock of your question is not a list of string elements, but a syntactically invalid series of single element lists each containing a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `\t` as delimeter, you should just change the line

```
sreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
```

to

```
sreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
```

No postprocessing needed.

Answer (score 2):

On what delimiter?  Have you seen the [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method available on all strings?

Comment: delimiter is \t. Yes, I have tried split but can't make use of it. It is always giving an error that list object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: ...yeah, because you split the string, not the list.  Where are you getting this data from?  A bunch of single element lists containing strings is somewhat of a strange format.

Comment: Its a csv file with spaces as deimiters.

Comment: @sr2222 `['somethingsomething']` is a single element list. `'somethingsomething'` would be a string. You need to use `listname[0].split()` with `listname = ['somethingsomething']`

Answer (score 0):

I’ll assume that what you have is a list of strings, not the series of single-element lists that you put in the question. You can do something like this:

```
strings = ['96\t00:00:00:19\t-16,894725\t15,201475\t26,976\t52,471\t10,081275\t42,177475\t32,0962',
  '97\t00:00:00:19\t-17,007775\t15,198775\t26,979\t52,471\t9,971225\t42,177775\t32,20655',
  '98\t00:00:00:19\t-17,010475\t15,204175\t26,977\t52,471\t9,966525\t42,181175\t32,21465',
  '99\t00:00:00:19\t-16,9997\t15,1907\t26,981\t52,473\t9,9813\t42,1717\t32,1904',
  '100\t00:00:00:20\t-17,0024\t15,17995\t26,979\t52,476\t9,9766\t42,15895\t32,18235']
split_strings = [string.split('\t') for string in strings]
```

This will yield a list of lists:

```
[['96', '00:00:00:19', '-16,894725', '15,201475', '26,976', '52,471', '10,081275', '42,177475', '32,0962'],
 ['97', '00:00:00:19', '-17,007775', '15,198775', '26,979', '52,471', '9,971225', '42,177775', '32,20655'],
 ['98', '00:00:00:19', '-17,010475', '15,204175', '26,977', '52,471', '9,966525', '42,181175', '32,21465'],
 ['99', '00:00:00:19', '-16,9997', '15,1907', '26,981', '52,473', '9,9813', '42,1717', '32,1904'],
 ['100', '00:00:00:20', '-17,0024', '15,17995', '26,979', '52,476', '9,9766', '42,15895', '32,18235']]
```

I hope this helps you get started.